# mobile app debug not working - flutter (but flutter run command is working)

Tags: flutter

I used in both vscode and android studio in
both of them - start debugging, run without debugging are not working

but flutter run is working through terminal

1. [android studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59S5U.png)
2. [vscode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynAz0.png)

flutter doctor - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVPRv.png)

mobile ui is simply white screen
nothing is working like hot reload or hot restart